# fb:request-form without redirection

Tags: facebook

I'd like to use a fb:request-form to invite a user's friends to an event. Since my application is on one page with lots of AJAX I don't want to redirect after the form is submitted. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML will be deprecated in a few days. There are other ways to do this. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ for example.